# how to fetch data from single table and show as multiple datatables using codeignator?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I'm fetching the data from the database. Want to show the data into multiple dataTables separated by column name (certification_scope).
This is the labels table in the database

[image]

Here is my Controller ***Clients.php***

```
  public function labels_data(){        
      $draw    = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
      $start   = intval($this->input->get("start"));
      $length  = intval($this->input->get("length"));
      $query   =   $this->db->select('*')->where('clientid',get_client_user_id())->order_by('labelid','desc')->get(db_prefix().'labels');
    
      $data = [];

      foreach($query->result() as $r) {
           $data[] = array(
                $r->certification_scope,
                $r->test_evidence,
                $r->c_scope_desc,
                $r->total_quantity,
                $r->current_balance,
                $r->project_name,
                $r->serial_no_from,
                $r->serial_no_to,
                $r->used_quantity                  
           );
      }
    
      $result = array(
                 "draw" => $draw,
                 "recordsTotal" => $query->num_rows(),
                 "recordsFiltered" => $query->num_rows(),
                 "data" => $data
            );
      echo json_encode($result);
      exit();
}
```

This is the view ***labels.php***

```
<div class="table-wrap">
                                <table id="item-list" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Certification Scope</th>
                                        <th>Test Evidence</th>
                                        <th>Scope Description</th>
                                        <th>Total Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Current Balance</th>
                                        <th>Project Name</th>
                                        <th>Serial No From</th>
                                        <th>Serial No To</th>
                                        <th>Used Quanity</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody> </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

This is the dataTable Ajax

```
             $('#item-list').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                url  : "<?php echo base_url('clients/labels_data'); ?>",
                type : 'GET'
            }
        });
```

Result for the above code is

[image]

Want to show the DataTables like this
[image]

Anyone can please help me to fix this.

Comment: Try the DataTables' `RowGroup` extension: https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/

Comment: @cheesyMan can you show me. if you have any demo?

Comment: You can find lots of examples if you dive into DataTables official documentation. https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/simple.html